# Argument List too Long for Everything besides default Terminal?

Tags: command-line, permissions, scripts, virtualbox

I am currently running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS on VirtualBox, when ever I try to use the terminal in visual studio code on the VirtualBox, I get the following message,

```
user@ubuntu:~/Documents/test$ ls
bash: /usr/bin/ls: Argument list too long
user@ubuntu:~/Documents/test$ mkdir
bash: /usr/bin/mkdir: Argument list too long
user@ubuntu:~/Documents/test$ tmux
bash: /usr/bin/tmux: Argument list too long
```

However, these default commands work if used in the default terminal. If I run tmux, and use the tmux created session, I can also no longer use the commands, giving me the same error, specifically `/usr/bin/...: Argument list is too long`

Is this because the bin folder is too large? It shouldn't be, only around 200mb. Any suggestions?

Edit:
When I run `getconf ARG_MAX` in default terminal, I get `2097152`

Comment: How many files and directories do you have in `~/Documents/test`? This sort of error is generally seen when working with really large directories 

Comment: currently it is empty, the only command that works is cd, even if I relocate to home directory, I still get the same error

Comment: I think it's likely to do with one or more *environment variables* that have grown out of control than anything in the specific directory - see for example [This command: “. .bashrc” has resulted in: “-bash: /usr/bin/whoami: Argument list too long” whenever I try to execute any command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/648319/this-command-bashrc-has-resulted-in-bash-usr-bin-whoami-argument-lis) and

Comment: @FedonKadifeli, I update my question

Comment: I might need to add that this .bashrc file is located in a user's directory, not at root.

Comment: Can your run these commands in the terminal in visual studio? `export|wc`, `env|wc`,  `set|wc`, and  `echo "$PATH"|wc`.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli or perhaps `myenv=$(declare -x); echo ${#myenv}` and `echo ${#PATH}` which only require shell builtins ...

Comment: @steeldriver your suggestion for that link has worked! thanks!

Comment: @AkashiLi Feel free to document your solution in an answer below. It is perfectly fine to answer your own question, and this would be very userful for future readers.